# Position the Title of Custom Joomla Module

Tags: php, joomla, module

I am trying to move the title of a custom module I built from the default top of the module to an area within the custom code (users have the ability to choose left or right in the options panel and I would like the title to be on the same side as the text.

I am able to get the title with:

```
if ($module->showtitle) {

echo $module-title;
}
```

However I still have the title above the module itself. How can I say "don't show the title in the default position, show it here" ?

Comment: Try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks! Asked there as well